# How do i auto approve new user?

Tags: users, user-registration

I am developing a social networking site on buddypress. and when a new user registers on my website, he gets an activation link in the email, and i have to manually activate his account from admin dashboard. i don't want to do this. i want their account to be activated from their activation email directly, without approving them from admin dashboard

Answer (score 2):

you can Disable users activation email:
https://buddypress.org/support/topic/resolved-disable-users-activation-email/
and there is plugin to do its:
https://timersys.com/free-plugins/bp-disable-activation-reloaded/